# How can I do like this web sites

Tags: javascript, json, build, helper

Today I found a web site and I liked it a lot of this web site. However I do not know how can I do that web site. so I don't know, they were using which language.

Can you help me ? Can you explain to me how can build web site like this?
(Exactly,I want to learn it.)

Thanks.

Ozan.

Please,[click here](http://www.thehappyforecast.com/) for web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any webpage build with mainly the 3 technologies listed below. You should have good knowledge  in these to build an webpage

> ```
> >     HTML - Hyper Text Markup Language 
> >     CSS - Cascading Style Sheets
> >     Javascript
> ```

Visit [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)  this will give you a good understanding

Comment: Hello dear friend,

I am a Junior Front End Developer but don't have enough skills for develop like it.

So I don't know how do like that web site.

by the way, i know css, html, php(oop), sql, little jquery,